# Right adjective for an unexpected solution to a math problem

Tags: word-choice

I asked for help about a mathematics problem on M.SE and someone answered with a valid proof resorting to a reasoning I wouldn't have imagined, without giving details about how he got that idea.

Is there an adjective or a phrase that qualifies such a proof? To a more general extent, how do you qualify the outcome of an operation (of the mind, or something concrete) that is unexpected but still satisfactory?

There's a French phrase for it: *sorti du chapeau*.

Comment: In English, we do not use spaces before our question marks or our colons.

Comment: Care to point to the math question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [pull something (sometimes a rabbit) out of a hat](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/pull+a+rabbit+out+of+your+hat.html) - that's the exact equivalent of your French idiom.

You can also produce something [out of the blue](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/out+of+the+blue.html), [from nowhere](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/From+nowhere?s=t), or out of [thin air](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Thin+air?s=t).